# d3 slider to change csv column

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, slider, queue

I have a d3 slider with a range from 2001 to 2016 and a csv file with columns name and no_2001 to no_2016. The csv is called in a d3.queue together with a json file to build a choropleth map changing over the years.

My problem is to change the column of the csv file by dragging the slider. Can anyone help? Thanks!

This is what I have so far. In the queue function "+d.no_2015" has to be changed, but my defined "column" does not work if I replace it with "+d.no_2015".

```
<h2>Year: <span id="year">2016</span></h2>
<div id="slider"></div>

<script>

function csvColumn(data){ 
    column = "no_" + data;
    return column // this does not work
};

d3.select('#slider').call(d3.slider()
    .min(2001)
    .max(2016)
    .value(2016) 
    .step(1)
    .axis(d3.svg.axis().tickFormat(d3.format(".0f")).ticks(16)) 
    .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
  d3.select('#year').text(value);
  csvColumn(value);
}));

var rateById = d3.map();

d3_queue.queue()
      .defer(d3.json, "de_landkreis.json")
      .defer(d3.csv, "maserndaten.csv", function(d) {rateById.set(d.name, +d.no_2015);}) //here the slider has to act. +d.column does not work.
      .await(showData);

function showData(error, de_landkreis) { ... }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve here... also, code is incomplete. What is `rateById` and `showData`? Also, when you call the function `cssColumn`, the value is totally ignored since it's not assigned to a variable or used in any form. Please explain your strategy.

Comment: Hi, `showData` builds with the json file the map and is not effected by the slider. 
`var rateById = d3.map();` helps to color the map looking at the values in the column "no_2015" in the csv file. 
I like to store the tick value of the slider, e.g. 2014, and replace than "no_2015" in the rateById function with "no_2014". 
I did not use the output of `cssColumn` in this code because it did not work if I replace `+d.no_2015` with `+d.column`. 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Ok, see answer below and check if it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if I got it right, you should change your code so the column defined by your slider is used instead to populate your map. This I think would do the trick:

```
<h2>Year: <span id="year">2016</span></h2>
<div id="slider"></div>

<script>
// This is the default value
var selectedColumn = "no_2014";

function csvColumn(data){ 
    return "no_" + data;
};

d3.select('#slider').call(
  d3.slider()
    .min(2001)
    .max(2016)
    .value(2016) 
    .step(1)
    .axis(d3.svg.axis().tickFormat(d3.format(".0f")).ticks(16)) 
    .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
      d3.select('#year').text(value);
      selectedColumn = csvColumn(value);
    })
);

var rateById = d3.map();

d3_queue.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "de_landkreis.json")
  .defer(d3.csv, "maserndaten.csv", function(d) {
    rateById.set(d.name, +d[csvColumn(selectedValue)]);
  })
  .await(showData);

function showData(error, de_landkreis) { ... }
</script>
```

Of course, you would need to wire it in a way that changing the slider triggers the redrawing of the data using a different column as source. But the first part is solved.